# How Can i Import example application from developer.android.com into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have downloaded the CustomView.zip from [developer android page](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html). 
I've tried to import this into Android Studio 2.2.0.12. But I am NOT able to do it.

I have also tried to create a empty project in order to import only the sources and XML. It does´t work either, I get a lot of duplicates XML definitions and even after resolving the duplicates the App crashes with some inflate exception.

So, i´m wondering, How can I import this into Android Studio in order to have a working project and run it to see the behavior and also to debug it

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the sample file, stupidly, it doesnt include any of the standard android framework files (gradle, manifest etc), so Android Studio will not be able to automatically import it.

To get round this you should create a new blank project, leave the mainactivity that is generated.

Then go in to the file structure of the new project and copy in the files from the sample in to the corresponding files. Make sure you overwrite the files in the new project.

Then go in to the code base in Android Studio and delete any imports that cant be found due to incorrect package names. Re import these (alt + enter on mac) with the correct package names and then build and you should be good to go.

Comment: Like i said, i have tried this. Doing that caused a few duplicated in XML definition items. i was able to solve them, but after that, When i compile and run it, It crashes during the inflation of the Custom View component

Comment: Post the stacktrace

Comment: i will give you a step by step detail performed later today, I am at work now, i have this at my Macbook at home.

Comment: There you go https://we<dot>tl/gZDa9dlriZ , thats a working implementation of the custom view, i suspect you forgot to change the name of the custom view i.e <PieChart> which is what would have been causing the inflation error (Replace <dot> with .)

Comment: As soon as I get there i will have a look, Thanks

Comment: Did you face the same duplicates on the XML attributes as i did?